# Wireless networking on Ubuntu 12.04 machine

Tags: wireless

My machine is dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. A new laptop with Ubuntu 12.04 made me reconfigure my modem. Now I have internet connectivity on Windows and the laptop, but not on Ubuntu. After booting, the wireless connection is established automatically, but I am not able to ping 192.168.1.1.

What I have done so far.

- Saw to it that the IP addresses on windows and Ubuntu is the same
- Added nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf` and
  `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
- `sudo resolvconf -u`
- `sudo service network-manager restart`

Still no connection.

**`ifconfig -a`** output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:71:bc:3c:3d:bc  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fb100000-fb120000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:28913 (28.9 KB)  TX bytes:28913 (28.9 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:bd:b9:81:3a:8f  
          inet addr:192.168.1.85  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1ebd:b9ff:fe81:3a8f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:742 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:89112 (89.1 KB)
```

---

**`nm-tool`** output:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

Device: wlan0 [www] --------------------------------------------------------- Type: 802.11 WiFi Driver: rt2800usb State: connected Default: yes HW Address: 1C:BD:B9:81:3A:8F

Capabilities: Speed: 36 Mb/s

Wireless Properties WEP Encryption: yes WPA Encryption: yes WPA2 Encryption: yes

Wireless Access Points (* = current AP) *www: Infra, 00:FD:07:9C:78:5B, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 63 WEP

IPv4 Settings: Address: 192.168.1.85 Prefix: 24 (255.255.255.0) Gateway: 192.168.1.1

DNS: 59.185.0.23

Device: eth0 ----------------------------------------------------------------- Type: Wired Driver: e1000e State: unavailable Default: no HW Address: 70:71:1D:3C:3D:BC

Capabilities: Carrier Detect: yes

Wired Properties Carrier: off
```

---

**`route`** output:

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination      Gateway       Genmask         Flags Metric Ref      Use  Iface


default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0   wlan0

link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0   wlan0

192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     2      0        0   wlan0
```

---

**`lsusb`** output:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1c4f:0003 SiGma Micro HID controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c31d Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 07d1:3c16 D-Link System DWA-125 Wireless N 150 Adapter(rev.A2) [Ralink RT3070]    
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0951:162d Kingston Technology
```

I checked `/etc` and found there was no wireless folder. I installed the driver for DWA-125 but still no connectivity.

Comment: What happens if you change the channel the WI-FI is broadcast on?

Comment: May we also see: nm-tool

Comment: What's the actual output of `ping -c 4 192.168.1.1`?

Comment: What is your O/P when runing `route` in terminal?